# Log flux until mono completes

Tags: project-reactor

I have the following:

```
Flux<String> flux = ...
Mono<Void> mono = ...


Mono<Void> combined = operation(flux, mono);
```

They represent operations happening in parallel.

Now, I would like to print all elements emitted by the `flux` to sysout  until `mono` completes, 
what's the right operator to use here?

I've tried :

```
final Disposable subscribe = flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
mono.doOnSuccessOrError((o, e) -> subscribe.dispose());
```

But if feels clumpsy, I have a feeling there might be a better way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

So, Project Reactor provides some methods to log emitted results:

- [doOnNext(Consumer onNext)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-)
- [subscribe(Consumer consumer)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-)
- [log()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#log--)

You can see how it works.

Code example:

```
Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.just("one", "two", "three")
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("On next: " + s));
    Mono<String> stringMono = Mono.just("four");

    stringFlux = stringFlux.concatWith(stringMono)
            .map(s -> s + " hundred")
            .log();

    stringFlux.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("On next subscriber: " + s));
```

Result:

```
15:32:18.984 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
15:32:18.986 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - request(unbounded)
On next: one
15:32:19.005 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(one hundred)
On next subscriber: one hundred
On next: two
15:32:19.005 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(two hundred)
On next subscriber: two hundred
On next: three
15:32:19.005 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(three hundred)
On next subscriber: three hundred
15:32:19.006 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(four hundred)
On next subscriber: four hundred
15:32:19.007 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onComplete()
```

First message has been written from `doOnNext` of `stringFlux`, after that `log` of combined Publishers and the last is `subscribe`.

P.S. Also you can log other events like OnError, OnComplete and etc.